# Display Tag is not working in tomcat. Any version issue?

Tags: java, tomcat, displaytag

I have created dynamic web module with EAR reference to deploy it in the Websphere 6.1.
Then we are requested to have it in the Tomcat 5.5 server. Display Tag is not populating data from action class.

My java version is pointing to websphere6.1 version, struts2, displaytag 1.2 tomcat 5.5.

Let me know the issue? Any compatibility issue?

I faced compatibility issue for struts2 in websphere 6.1. Is it anything similar for tomcat?

Comment: And what does it do instead? Any exception?

Comment: i didn't get any exception. it shows empty block in that table area.

Comment: Please show application code in that case.

Also, are you sure that it is receiving any input data? For example, try to print out the table data using a <c:out> tag